# Access violation reading location C++ char vector

Tags: c++

I'm newbie in C++, and I'm having some problems with this new language :)
I can't find where I am not working ok with the memory, because I never have worked with a language that don't manage the memory by itself.
I hope someone can help me.

The error is "Access violation reading location".

Sorry for my bad English, I'm Uruguayan.

```
        dopartial:
        test    edx,1
        jz      short doword

        ***mov     al,[edx]***   //here i get the error
```

```
int CalcularCantPalabras(char* str, int largo, char* delimitador){          
    int largo_VectorRetorno = 0;
    char *palabra_cortada =  new char[largo]+1;
    strcpy_s(palabra_cortada ,largo+1,str);
    palabra_cortada = strtok(palabra_cortada,delimitador);
    while( palabra_cortada!= NULL ){
        palabra_cortada = strtok(NULL,delimitador);
        largo_VectorRetorno++;
    }   
    return largo_VectorRetorno;
}


char** splitStr(char* str, char separador, int &largoRet){
    char *delimitador = new char[1];
    delimitador[0] = separador;
    int largo_string = strlen(str);
    char* str_copia = new char[largo_string];
    strcpy_s(str_copia,largo_string+1,str);
    int largo_VectorRetorno = CalcularCantPalabras(str_copia,largo_string,delimitador);
    char ** VectorRetorno = new char*[largo_VectorRetorno];
    largoRet = largo_VectorRetorno;
    int posicion_vec_retorno = 0;
    str_copia = strtok(str_copia-1,delimitador);
    VectorRetorno[posicion_vec_retorno] = str_copia;
    posicion_vec_retorno = posicion_vec_retorno+1;
    while( str_copia!= NULL && posicion_vec_retorno<largo_VectorRetorno){
        posicion_vec_retorno++;
        str_copia = strtok(NULL,delimitador);
        VectorRetorno[posicion_vec_retorno] = str_copia;    
    }
    return VectorRetorno;
}
```

Comment: You are not using a char vector, that would be called `std::vector<char>`. It manages its own memory and good debuggers will perform bounds-checking.

Comment: Your code is very hard to read.

Answer (score 3):

```
char *palabra_cortada =  new char[largo]+1;
```

This should be:

```
char *palabra_cortada =  new char[largo+1];
```

Because your `+1` is outside the `[]`, it has no effect on the size of the array. So `largo` is the size, not `largo+1`. Then you get hit by a double whammy. `new char[largo]` is performed and gives you a pointer to the first element of the array. You then accidentally add 1, which is moving the pointer to the second element of the array.

Instead of your array going from `0` to `largo+1`, it goes from `1` to `largo`. Effectively, your array is short two elements. This is most likely the root of your problem.

Comment: The line after that should, most likely, be `strcpy_s(palabra_cortada ,largo,str);`.